# Refresh page after deleting in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I need to delete a user from my material table, but the page doesn't refresh.
It's okay in my console but nothing happen in the table.

If i fetch user like I do in my NgonInit, it reloads the whole table, not the data after deleting.

ts file

```
  deleteUser(user) {
    this.dataSource.data.splice(this.dataSource.data.indexOf(user), 1);
    console.log(user); // I have the good user
    console.log(this.dataSource.data); // my table is updated
  }
```

when I call my function to call my users

```
this.http.get("./assets/data/user.json")
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.dataSource.data = response;
          console.log(this.dataSource.data) // I have the inital table of users
        },
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

The `mat-table` will not detect the changes in your `dataSource` if it is changed through mutation, it will only re-render if the array reference is changed. Try updating the `data` in the `dataSource` immutably after you use your `splice` function like below.

```js
this.dataSource.data.splice(this.dataSource.data.indexOf(user), 1);
this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data];
```

Or if you have a unique value, say `id` in `user`, you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) since it creates a new array.

```js
deleteUser (id) {
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(user => user.position !== id);
}
```

where `id` is the `id` of the `user` you want to delete.

Comment: Can you tell me how pass data through components and refresh the main table ?

Comment: You can use `@Input` and `@Output` if it's a parent-child relationship. See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) to see all the ways you can interact between components. If you still have problems, create a new question since it is not related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a variable for holding data:

```
const data;
this.http.get("./assets/data/user.json")
    .subscribe(
        (response) => {
            this.data = response;
            this.dataSource.data = data;
            console.log(this.dataSource.data) // I have the inital table of users
        },
```

And when you delete:

```
deleteUser(user) {
   this.data.splice(this.data.indexOf(user), 1);
   this.dataSource.next(this.data);
   console.log(user); // I have the good user
   console.log(this.dataSource.data); // my table is updated
}
```

The line `this.dataSource.next(this.data);` notifies that data is changed and changes are reflected then.

***Not tested but try if that works:***

```
deleteUser(user) {
  this.dataSource.data.splice(this.dataSource.data.indexOf(user), 1);
  this.dataSource.next(this.dataSource.data);
}
```